# Is the jq + operator eager?

Tags: jq, operator-precedence

I originally wrote my jq command as

```
.data.viewer.zones[] | .httpRequests1mGroups[0].sum|with_entries(select(.key|endswith("Map")|not))  + {"zoneTag": .zoneTag}
```

and got this result:

```
{
  "bytes": 2875120330,
  "cachedBytes": 1475518778,
  "zoneTag": null
}
{
  "bytes": 2875120330,
  "cachedBytes": 1475518778,
  "zoneTag": null
}
```

`zoneTag` is the last attribute in a `zones` object.

I rewrote the command as

```
.data.viewer.zones[] |  {"zoneTag": .zoneTag} +   .httpRequests1mGroups[0].sum|with_entries(select(.key|endswith("Map")|not))
```

and get what I expected:

```
{
  "zoneTag": "zone 1",
  "bytes": 2875120330,
  "cachedBytes": 1475518778,
}
{
  "zoneTag": "zone 2",
  "bytes": 2875120330,
  "cachedBytes": 1475518778,
}
```

My question is why? Is `+` eager? (I get the same results using `*`.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So maybe you're looking for an explanation in terms of operator precedence.

Let:

A represent `.data.viewer.zones[]`

B represent `.httpRequests1mGroups[0].sum`

C represent `with_entries(select(.key|endswith("Map")|not))`

Then your first jq expression is equivalent to

```
A | B | C + {zoneTag}
```

whereas your second is equivalent to:

```
A  | {zoneTag} + B | C
```

So in the first case, `{zoneTag}` gets its value from B but in the
second case, it comes from A.

Answer (score 1):

In jq, for most purposes, including that of object addition, an explicit null value in the object on the right is not the same as the absence of a key.

Thus if A is `{"a": 1}` then `A + {}` is A but `A + {"a": null}` is {"a": null}.

Thus the "right-most value" rule must be understood to mean "right-most explicit value".

Whether any of this has to do with "eagerness" depends on your understanding of that term.

### Non-lazy evaluation

In jq, object addition (and indeed addition in general) proceeds from right to left and is of course non-lazy, as can be seen in the following example, which also illustrates the RHS-dominance mentioned above.

```
jq -n '{a:(1|debug)} + {b: (2|debug)} + {a:(3|debug)}'
["DEBUG:",3]
["DEBUG:",2]
["DEBUG:",1]
{
  "a": 3,
  "b": 2
}
```

So far as I know, though, the right-associativity might not be guaranteed.

Comment: Hmm. Thanks. So it's not eagerness in the RE sense but that doesn't explain why `zoneTag` is null when it's on the right- or does it?

Comment: I know what eagerness refers to in the context of RE and evaluation in general.  jq addition is obviously not "lazy" but I'm not sure what relevance that has here.  If jq had a short-circuit semantics for object addition, that would be relevant, but it doesn't.

Comment: So let’s forget eager and lazy, why does the `zoneTag` capture fail on the right of the `+`?